# How to manipulate the DOM before in-page scripts are executed?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), how can I run a script in the page context, with the full DOM available, before the in-page JS is executed?

For example, how can I run the following script to remove `alt` attributes from `img` elements, before any of the page JS is run?

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]').forEach(
  e => e.removeAttribute('alt')
)
```

([`page.evaluateOnNewDocument`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) looks like it would be useful, but it appears to be executed before the page content is available--at the point at which it runs, the page is blank.)

Answer (score 9):

I think the way to achieve what you are looking for is to perform:

1. set [`page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled)
2. enter the page
3. extract all the scripts and HTML without scripts
4. set `page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`
5. enter `` page.goto(`data:text/html,${HTMLWithoutScript}`) `` with HTML from step 3
6. execute your scripts
7. incject original extracted scripts `page.addScriptTag({ content: script })` from step 3

---

## Example

Here is a visualization of your problematic example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1062" alt="dog ">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1072" alt="car ">
        <div class="alts">List of alts: </div>
        <script>
            const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
            const altsContainer = document.querySelector('.alts');
            images.forEach(image => {
                const alt = image.getAttribute('alt') || 'missing alt ';
                altsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', alt);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]').forEach(
            e => e.removeAttribute('alt')
        )
    });
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'image.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This code produce:

[image: broken example]

So remove alts is not working here.

### solution

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);
    const { script, HTMLWithoutScript } = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const script = document.querySelector('script').innerHTML;
        document.querySelector('script').innerHTML = '';
        const HTMLWithoutScript = document.body.innerHTML;
        return { script, HTMLWithoutScript }
    });
    
    await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${HTMLWithoutScript}`);
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]').forEach(
            e => e.removeAttribute('alt')
        )
    });
    await page.addScriptTag({ content: script });
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'image.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This will produce results as you expect in a question:

[image: working example]

Answer (score 0):

You can move your script tags to body instead of head. Then using document onload event you can execute a script. According to MDN this event fires when an object has been loaded. Below is the example code

```js
function removeAlt(){
  document.querySelectorAll('img[alt]').forEach((e)=>{
    e.removeAttribute('alt');
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="removeAlt()">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="2">
</body>
```

Let me know whether this fits into your requirement, I tested and function is removing alt tags from image

Comment: Does this apply when using Puppeteer? I'm not sure how to move the script to the body.

Comment: It's not specific to Puppeteer for any browser. To move script tag for example you have  <script src="somefile.js"></script> inside head tag now just move <script src="somefile.js"></script> block inside body (i.e. Before closing body tag)

Comment: When/how is the script injected though? As soon as you call [page.goto()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), Puppeteer seems to start executing the existing JS on the page--there's no time to inject the JS and have it run before the backing browser runs the JS on the page.